# Entropy change in sudden expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

For an irreversible sudden expansion from $V$ to $2V$, no heat is added during the expansion. However, the entropy changes by $N\log2$. I'm not sure how there can be a change in entropy without any heat added, since $dS = \frac{dQ}{T} = 0$. Of course, integration can yield $\Delta S = C$, where $C$ is a constant, but I'm not sure if this is the correct mathematical and physical way of thinking about this. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: The relation is  $T\Delta S\ge \Delta Q$ with equality only for *reversible* changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entropy change in the free expansion of a gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527438/179151)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original equation is incorrect.  The entropy change is not $\Delta S=\int{\frac{dq}{T}}$.  The correct equation is$$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dq_{rev}}{T}}$$ where $dq_{rev}$ is the heat flow for an alternate reversible process between the same two end states.  For such a reversible path, the heat flow will not be zero.